# How to set up an emission node within the cracks of a surface to spill

Tags: node-editor, animation-nodes, emission

I have a node set up with cracks on a surface. I'd like within the cracks an emission to give the impression its spreading (like the Yellow example),so I can animate it depending on the value.
if possible from the centre core of the surface towards its boundaries.

[image]

Comment: I tried using this node set up as well, seeing a tutorial but its not working. But am I on the right path? 

https://ibb.co/wBmjdyg

Comment: I think this will help you.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/u96o7.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWtK6.png

Comment: Hello, I have set up the same node as your first screenshot, but the result is different, what have I missed? https://ibb.co/hWYjpj2

Comment: The first `color ramp` node value is not good and the second thing is the `mapping` node `location` values are different.

Comment: Thanks for that, I just saw it, because the screen shot with the node values are a bit small.